# Program crashes while assigning vector's element to another one

Tags: c++

my program is about reading data from a file. File consists of 5 lines, each stores one player's data (name, surname, height, 5 abilities) which are separated by semi-colon. Here is the method to extract data within Player class:

```
// Extracting data from text file
vector<string> split(string line, char delimiter) {
    vector<string> data;
    string character;
    stringstream charStream(line);
    while (getline(charStream, character, delimiter))
    {
        data.push_back(character);
    }
    name = data[0];
    surname = data[1];
    height = stoi(data[2]);
    // After this line program crashes
    skills[0] = data[3];
    return data;
}

// Checking whether a given file exists
string file_name, line;
string arr[5];
int i = 0;
cout << "Enter file name with an extension: ";
cin >> file_name;
ifstream file;
file.open(file_name);
// Sending data to the class Player and Team to be organized if a file exists
if (file.good()) {
        while (getline(file, line)) {
            arr[i] = line;
            i++;
        }
    Player p11(arr[0]);
    p11.split(arr[0], ';');
    Player p12(arr[1]);
    p12.split(arr[1], ';');
    Player p13(arr[2]);
    p13.split(arr[2], ';');
    Player p14(arr[3]);
    p14.split(arr[3], ';');
    Player p15(arr[4]);
    p15.split(arr[4], ';');
```

And here constructors:

```
class Player {
public:
string name, surname, line;
int height;
vector<string> skills;

// Default constructor
Player(string name, string surname, int height, vector<string> skills) : name(name), surname(surname),
    height(height), skills(skills) {}

// File constructor
Player(string line) : line(line) {}
```

The question is why can't I assign these strings describing abilities to the vector storing skills?

```
 // After this line program crashes
skills[0] = data[3];
return data;
```

Comment: The `skills` vector is of size 0, so trying to assigne to index `0` will crash. Use `push_back` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign to a vector element like an array while its a non-existent. Instead use of this :

```
skills.push_back(data[3]);
```

Because the `0` element of skills does not exist yet. and `skills[0]` cause to crash.